# logout flow facebook sdk IOS   [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth: NO]; 

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, authentication, logout

all questions on the facebook ios sdk for login and logout and Safari have been solved without adding the file facebook.m the line of code `[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]`, but in the new facebook SDK this file is outdated and not used in the library of the framework as such then my question is what is the current solution to this problem thank you very much

Comment: I have this problem , do you solve it ?